# SQL Server 2014 - No services installed in SQL Configuration Manager

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Installed Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014 Express , but I can't find SQL Server Services to run it in the "SQL Server Configuration Manager", so I can't connect to SQL server.

It's a problem because when I launch Sql Server Management Studio and that I try to connect me on the database server with server name "(local)", "localhost", "SQLEXPRESS",(local)/SQLEXPRESS, it doesn't work

I've seen in services.msc and I saw "SQL Server VSS Writer" launched automatically.

Do you have a solution ?

Thank you

Comment: I think you have installed only SQL Server Management Studio not SQL Server itself.

Comment: When I install SQL Server(SQLManagementStudio_x86_FRA.exe), I've selected all the components

Answer (score 6):

If you download from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299, make sure use `SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe` or `SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe`. `SQLManagementStudio_x86_FRA.exe` does not contains database engine.

Comment: I first had downloaded the management studio only. Then I got the file you mentioned and installed LocalDB. I saw the confirmation. But still no service is showing up in Services or when I click Browse in connection window of SQL Server Management Studio 2014. Has anyone tried it?

Answer (score 3):

I want to think that I had the same issue. When this happened to me, I went to the Configuration Manager only to learn that I had no Services whatsoever. I solved it by installing the SQL Server Express with with Advanced Services version from [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx).

I don't know whether you do need all its functionality, though. But what I do know is that it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually, I am pretty sure, that you have installed the Management Studio, not the Database Engine itself. You have to install the Database Engine. The response @Edward gave will lead you to the Database Engine for SQL Server Express 2014, that will do the trick.
I hope this helps to clarify what the problem was.